# C - Reading files passed as command line argument

Tags: c, readfile

I am a newbie to C coding, and I am working on a project. There is a problem I couldn't solve. I am trying to count the words in a given text file (passed as an argument), but every time I got the result "file can't open"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *fptr;
  char ch;
  int w = 0;

  /* char filename[15];
  printf("Enter the filename to be opened \n");
  scanf("%s", filename);
  open the file for reading
  fptr = fopen(filename, "r"); */

  /* argc must be 2 for correct execution */
  if (argc != 2) {
    /* Assume that argv[0] is the program name */
    printf("usage: %s, <file_name>", argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf("can't open file");
  }
  else {
    ch = fgetc(fptr);
    while (ch != EOF) {
      if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
        w++;
      }
      ch = fgetc(fptr);
    }
    printf("\nWords in a file are=%d", w);
    printf("\n");
  }
  fclose(fptr);
}
```

the output should be the number of words in the file, but each time I tried it I got the result can't open file

```
./CountWords  test.txt
Can't open file
```

When I tried to change by asking the user to enter the file name (as what I put in comments and I just do it to know where is the error) it works, and I got the number of words. But this doesn't help me because am working on project that needs to count the number of words in a file passing as command line argument.

```
char filename[15];
    printf("Enter the filename to be opened \n");
      scanf("%s", filename);
    open the file for reading 
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
```

That means the code works but the problem is only in reading files passed as command line arguments. I searched for similar problems and tried their solutions, and I wrote an existing code from other tutorials that read files as command line argument but the problem is the same.

I use Linux, and I tried to use different files in different paths but the problem wasn't fixed.

Comment: Instead of `printf("can't open file");` try `perror(argv[1]);`.  It will tell you why the file cannot be opened and may shed light on the problem.

Comment: Did you check what is being mentioned in the answer?

Comment: What you've posted doesn't compile (you're missing a `;` after the assignment of fptr), so this is clearly not the code you're actually using.  The problem may lie in the difference.  Post your actual code.

Comment: Note that error messages should be printed on standard error, not standard output.  A good design for many processes is to read files (plural) on the command line, or from standard input if no files are listed.  Think `grep`.  One easy way to implement that is to have a function which is given an open `FILE *` and possibly a file name, and then have the `main()` program process each argument (open the file, call the function, close the file) or pass standard input to the function.

Comment: Does the file exist in your current working directory? Do you have read permission for that file?

Comment: yes it's already exist and I have read permission

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a more structured way to write the code which will help you in debugging.

```
FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
if(fp == NULL){
   perror("fopen");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

On most library implementations, the `errno` variable is also set to a ***system-specific error code*** on failure, which might be of immense help in this case.

Commenting on your alternate code:- (check the return value of `scanf` and this helps in getting the  status of the input to you).

```
if(scanf("%14s",filename)!=1){
   //error occured
}
```

Comment: I did it, but I still don't know what is the error :( I got "No such file or directory segmentation fault"

Comment: @user2033888 If there is a segmentation fault, start using a debugger. Run your program in GDB and see where the segfault happens.

Answer (score 1):

While there is nothing wrong with checking `if (argc != 2)` and handling everything within an `if` block, you can add the flexibility to either read from the given filename (or from `stdin` by default if no filename is given) by using a simple *ternary* operator checking the value of `argc` and then either opening the file or assigning `stdin` to the file pointer. (the code presumes if the file is not open it is due to an invalid filename given instead of `stdin` not being readable)

Further, rather than leaving everything nested within an `if`, if you check and your file isn't open, you can just `return` or `exit` at that point. That allows the remainder of your code to be written outside an `if` block.

A short example.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* use ternary operator to open file given as argv[1] or read stdin */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* do your stuff here */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

Either way, either checking for a required argument, or using the ternary to default to reading from `stdin` is fine, as long as you validate you have a file open for reading. This is just a bit of flexibility to add to your C toolbox.

Comment: While the suggestions are generally not bad, how does it even come close to being an answer to the question?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution of the problem by assigning initial value to fptr 
FILE *fptr = Null

Comment: This is not answer to the question. First of all it needs to read `= NULL;` for it to be valid C and secondly it is not necessary to initialize if the pointer is obtained from a call to `fopen` later before using it for anything else. (Assuming correct error handling).

Answer (score -2):

I was facing same issue but found the solution. I was including .txt in file name that why it was unable to find the file.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. `.txt` must be included in the file name for `fopen` to open it, if and only if the filename contains that extension.